# Как из двух списков внести значения в словарь?

Tags: python-3.x

Как из двух списков внести значения в словарь?
То есть есть два списка

```
s = ['Python 2.7.15', 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.616
1', 'Google Update Helper', 'VMware Tools']

s2 = ['2.7.15150', '9.0.30729.6161', '1.3.33.17', '10.1.15.6627299']
```

И есть пустой словарь, мне надо сделать чтобы из первого списка шли в словарь как ключ, а из второго списка как значения.

Вот мой набросок кода, но он не так работает:

```
for x in s2:
    for j in s:
        dct.update({j:x})
print (dct)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [zip](https://younglinux.info/python/feature/zip) и [конструктором словаря](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html)

```
dict(zip(s1,s2))
```